# Let $M = \{(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell^1 \mid x_n > 0 \text{ for all } n = 1,2, \dots \}$. Is $M$ an open subset of $\ell^1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

> Let $M = \{(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty \in \ell^1 \mid x_n > 0 \text{ for all } n = 1,2, \dots \}$. Is $M$ an open subset of $\ell^1$?

How should I think about this problem? If $M$ is open, then for any $x_n \in M$ I should be able to find an open ball $B(x_n,r) \subset M$, but I don't know what kind of topology are we talking about here. If for example $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$, then $x_n \in M$ and now the open ball should be an interval? So is there an $r > 0$ such that $(x_n-r, x_n+r) \subset M$? I think not as $x_n$ get arbitarily close to $0$ so subtracting any positive real number $r$ from $x_n$ will result in $x_n-r < 0$ which would mean that $(x_n-r,x_n+r)$ is not contained in $M$. Am I wrong here with my intuition and is the set actually open?

Edit: Let $x_n= 2^{-n}$. Now as $x_n \in \ell ^1$ we have that for any $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $$\sum_{n=N}^\infty |x_n| < \varepsilon.$$ Now let $y_k = \begin{cases} x_k, & k\le N \\ 0, & k >N \end{cases}$. The sequence $y_k$ is not in $M$, but $$\|x_n-y_n\|_1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n-y_n| = \sum_{n=1}^{N}|x_n-y_n| + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty |x_n -y_n|$$ but by how $y_k$ is defined $$\sum_{n=1}^{N}|x_n-y_n|  = 0$$ and $$\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty |x_n -y_n| = \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty |x_n| < \varepsilon$$ therefore $$\|x_n-y_n\|_1 < \varepsilon$$ so there does not exists an open ball around $x_n$ such that it would be contained in $M$. Is this a correct proof?

Comment: The sequence, $(\frac{1}{n})_1^\infty$ you have given is not in $\ell^1$, since $||(x_n)||_1 = \sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

Comment: First, try to really discern what your $M$ is. The elements of $M$ are sequences, and as such the elements you'll compare your sequence $(x_n)_n$ to in order to make your open ball are sequences, not reals. In the same logic, you can't ask an interval to be part of $M$.

Comment: HINT: $M$ is not an open subset of $\ell^1$. Think about the sequence $(2^{-n})_n \in M$, no open ball centered at it is contained in $M$.

Comment: @BrunoB By comparing elements what do you mean exactly? I know that $M$ is a set consisting of sequences, but I don't know how to talk about an open set containing an element of $M$.

Comment: @Crostul What is the argument that no open ball centered at $(2^{-n})_n$ is not contained in $M$?

Comment: When in doubt, go back to the definition of an open ball in an arbitrary normed space, and then try to make it clear in your mind about "who's who" in your situation, as in what space do you work in, what norm, etc...

Comment: $\ell^1$ is a metric space. There is the notion of *distance* between two sequences. The distance is $$d_1((x_n)_n;(y_n)_n) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n-y_n|$$ Now, try to show that for all $\varepsilon >0$ there exists a sequence $(y_n)_n \notin M$ which is $\varepsilon$ - close to the sequence $(2^{-n})_n$.

Comment: As for the argument of non-openness (which should be doable with any sequence of $M$? though working with a concrete example can help), it's in a way close to what you tried to do actually, I think (unless Crostul thought of something different)

Comment: I think that if $y_n = -2^{-n}$, then $y_n \notin M$ and $$\|x_n - y_n\|_1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \left | \frac{2}{2^n} \right | = 2$$ but these are not $\varepsilon$-close, but if I take $B(x_n, 3)$, then $y_n \in B(x_n, 3)$ @Crostul

Comment: The proof you posted in your edit is correct. Good job.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a short proof that $M$ does not even have interior.

Suppose $\mathbf{y}\in\ell_1(\mathbb{N})$ such that $\mathbf{y}(n)>0$ for all $n$. Given $\varepsilon>0$ there is $N=N_\varepsilon$ such that $\mathbf{y}(n)<\varepsilon$ for all $n\geq N$. Define
$\mathbf{y}'=\mathbf{y}-(\mathbf{y}(N)+\varepsilon/2)\mathbb{1}_{\{N\}}$, Then $\mathbf{y}'(N)=-\varepsilon/2<0$ and yet
$\|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{y}'\|_1=\varepsilon/2<\varepsilon$. This says that no ball $B(\mathbf{y},\varepsilon)=\{\mathbf{x}\in\ell_1:\|\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{y}\|_1<\varepsilon\}$ in $\ell_1$ is fully contained in $M$.